# how to calculating time difference between two times?

Tags: javascript

i have written code to calculate times between two times,this is my code

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
```

//javascript

```
 calculateDiff();

function calculateDiff(){
var _start = document.getElementsByName("usr").value;
var _end = document.getElementsByName("usr2").value;

    _start_time = parseAMDate(_start);
    _end_time = parseAMDate(_end);

    if (_end_time < _start_time){
        _end_time = parseAMDate(_end,1);
    }

    var difference= _end_time - _start_time;

    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5),
        minutes = Math.floor(difference % 36e5 / 60000);
    if (parseInt(hours) >= 0 ){
        if (minutes == 0){
            minutes = "00";
        }
        alert(hours+":"+minutes);
    }
}

function parseAMDate(input, next_day) {

    var dateReg = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})\s*(AM|PM)/;

    var hour, minute, result = dateReg.exec(input);

    if (result) {
        hour = +result[1];
        minute = +result[2];

        if (result[3] === 'PM' && hour !== 12) {
            hour += 12;
        }
    }
    if (!next_day) {
        return new Date(1970, 01, 01, hour, minute).getTime();
    }else{
        return new Date(1970, 01, 02, hour, minute).getTime();
    }
}
```

//form

```
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form> 
Select  start time:<input type="time" name="usr" id="startTime">
Select  end time: <input type="time" name="usr2" id="endTime">
<input type="button" value="cal" onclick="calculateDiff()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if i was executing this i am not getting the output,plz help me

when i was running this code, i was getting out put

```
     calculateDiff();

     function calculateDiff(){
    _start = "01:00 AM";
    _end = "02:00 AM";

    _start_time = parseAMDate(_start);
    _end_time = parseAMDate(_end);

    if (_end_time < _start_time){
        _end_time = parseAMDate(_end,1);
    }

    var difference= _end_time - _start_time;

    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5),
        minutes = Math.floor(difference % 36e5 / 60000);
    if (parseInt(hours) >= 0 ){
        if (minutes == 0){
            minutes = "00";
        }
        alert(hours+":"+minutes);
    }
}

function parseAMDate(input, next_day) {

    var dateReg = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})\s*(AM|PM)/;

    var hour, minute, result = dateReg.exec(input);

    if (result) {
        hour = +result[1];
        minute = +result[2];

        if (result[3] === 'PM' && hour !== 12) {
            hour += 12;
        }
    }
    if (!next_day) {
        return new Date(1970, 01, 01, hour, minute).getTime();
    }else{
        return new Date(1970, 01, 02, hour, minute).getTime();
    }
}
```

How to get the above code to be executed?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: I think you have the code duplicated, please clean up. And also clarify if there is an error or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that `_start` and `_end` are `undefined`:

```
var _start = document.getElementsByName("usr").value;
var _end = document.getElementsByName("usr2").value;
```

before you where using:

```
_start = "01:00 AM";
_end = "02:00 AM";
```

so it worked.

`document.getElementsByName()` is returning an array:

```
document.getElementsByName("usr")[0].value
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    //javascript


    window.onload = calculateDiff;

    function calculateDiff() {
      var _start = document.getElementsByName("usr")[0].value;
      var _end = document.getElementsByName("usr2")[0].value;
      
      
      _start_time = parseAMDate(_start);
      _end_time = parseAMDate(_end);

      if (_end_time < _start_time) {
        _end_time = parseAMDate(_end, 1);
      }

      var difference = _end_time - _start_time;

      var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5),
        minutes = Math.floor(difference % 36e5 / 60000);
      if (parseInt(hours) >= 0) {
        if (minutes == 0) {
          minutes = "00";
        }
        alert(hours + ":" + minutes);
      }
    }

    function parseAMDate(input, next_day) {

      var dateReg = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})\s*(AM|PM)/;

      var hour, minute, result = dateReg.exec(input);

      if (result) {
        hour = +result[1];
        minute = +result[2];

        if (result[3] === 'PM' && hour !== 12) {
          hour += 12;
        }
      }
      if (!next_day) {
        return new Date(1970, 01, 01, hour, minute).getTime();
      } else {
        return new Date(1970, 01, 02, hour, minute).getTime();
      }
    }

     //form
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    Select start time:
    <input type="time" name="usr" id="startTime">Select end time:
    <input type="time" name="usr2" id="endTime">
    <input type="button" value="cal" onclick="calculateDiff()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: here the alert message was not comming (out put)

Comment: That because your input does not have an "AM" or "PM" appended, but your code only works with that.

Comment: if the out put should come in new textbox means what has to add in code ?

Comment: instead of `alert(hours+":"+minutes);` use sth like `document.getElementByid("myTextbox").innerText = hours+":"+minutes`